# Searching for messages in Gmail sent by myself to myself

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

When sending email in Gmail, the last message in the mail is sometimes sent by me. I hit the reply button, meaning to send the email to everyone else, but the email ends up being addressed only to myself.

What happens next is that I end up wondering for several days why no-one has replied before checking the mail and discovering the mistake that I made.

Is there any way to filter mail in Gmail sent from myself to myself? I use my Gmail as a client to send mail from multiple accounts.

The current search I'm attempting is as such, but it's not working as I would like it to.

```
(From: johndoe@gmail.com OR johndoe@outlook.com -*) AND (To: johndoe@gmail.com OR johndoe@outlook.com -*)
```

Comment: My understanding of adding the "-" to a search is that it will exclude those matching things, and * seems like a rather broad wildcard to exclude.  Are the results even worse if you take out that exclusion on both the 'From' and 'To'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the two halves `(From:...)` and `(To:...)` are enclosed in parenthesis, I think you will get more accurate results if you prefix both addresses in each half with the `From:` or `To:` accordingly(see below).  As it is now, I think it is searching for the second email address of each half anywhere in any message.

Example:

```
(From: johndoe@gmail.com OR From: johndoe@outlook.com) AND (To: johndoe@gmail.com OR To: johndoe@outlook.com)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The problem why that doesn't work is that I still get mail that I send to a mailing list that I am a member of; Ideally, I would like to search for mail that is only sent to me. (This is the mail that causes real problems)

Comment: I see @VincentTjeng . Do those mailing list emails contain anything in the 'To' like "on behalf of" that you might be able to exclude perhaps?

Comment: After investigating further, I realize that this was my mistake. In all those mails which I thought were wrongly flagged, I had in fact cc-ed myself within the mail (which Google interprets as being included under a 'to:' ) Your method works well - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found worked:

```
from:me to:me
```

Comment: I'll wager this is actually better, because Gmail will know of your other email addresses as well (assuming you've added them to your profile).

Comment: @AlE. Unfortunately that leads to a lot of false positives when I tried it, mostly for domain names including `me` (for example, `johndoe@me.com`, or `johndoe@foo.me`). `me.com` is a real domain name while `foo.me` is anonymized, of course.